# Unable to install @angular/cli , Angular OpenSSL configuration error

Tags: powershell, angular-cli

I am trying to install Angular CLI , ran as admin, and got the following errors

```
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node 
./bin/postinstall/script.js
npm ERR! OpenSSL configuration error:
npm ERR! 74160000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such 
 file or 
directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling 
 fopen(C:\Program 
Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
npm ERR! 74160000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such 
file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
npm ERR! 74160000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no 
such 
file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Actually I have added OPENSSL for postgre sql thats why It was causing this error. By the way I was installing ionic CLI.
So, go to environment variables, System variables and search for OPENSS_CONF and delete it. For me I deleted this and it worked.

[image]

Comment: This solution is really helpful. After scratching and surfing through the internet I finally found the solution, Thanks a lot.